# "spyObj.plan is undefined" in Jasmine test

Tags: javascript, jasmine, jasmine-maven-plugin

I'm having a method called doLogin that calls another method login from another object.

```
doLogin : function(data) {
        var userMgtRequest = new UserMgtRequest();

        userMgtRequest.setLoginId(data.username);
        userMgtRequest.setLoginPwd(data.password);

        var callback = this.callbackLogin;
        userMgtManager.login(userMgtRequest, callback);
    }
```

I am trying to test, with jasmine, if the in-function login is really being called or not when I call the main function. So I put a couple of spies on the two functions and using "**andCallThrough(**)" to go into the actual implementation.
But when I do call the first (doLogin) function

```
logInController.doLogin(data);
```

I get this error :
**TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined**

Tracked it with Jasmine to this call :

```
jasmine.createSpy = function(name) {

var spyObj = function() {
  spyObj.wasCalled = true;
  spyObj.callCount++;
  var args = jasmine.util.argsToArray(arguments);
  spyObj.mostRecentCall.object = this;
  spyObj.mostRecentCall.args = args;
  spyObj.argsForCall.push(args);
  spyObj.calls.push({object: this, args: args});
  return spyObj.plan.apply(this, arguments);
};
```

Can anyone tell me what is the **spyObj.plan** property and why is it being undefined ?

**Edit : 
Looking at the jasmine.js source file, I have known that the plan property is the function the spy is going to call  depending on how it have been called. 
[jasmine.js.source](http://www.sourcexref.com/xref/mediawiki/nav.html?tests/jasmine/lib/jasmine-1.0.1/jasmine.js.source.html)

Answer (score 0):

It appeared that I was malforming the definition of my file. 
Same problem resolved here : [Mismatched definition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23796019/uncaught-error-mismatched-anonymous-define-module-function-definitionname)