# I'm getting a Uncaught Error: Mismatched anonymous define() module:

Tags: d3.js, requirejs, moodle

How do I fix this Mismatched anonymous define() module error in the c3 library?

(just upgraded to moodle 3.9)

Uncaught Error: Mismatched anonymous define() module: function(){function l(t){var e=this;e.d3=window.d3?window.d3:"undefined"!=typeof require?require("d3"):void 0,e.api=t,e.config=e.getDefaultConfig(),e.data={},e.cache={},e.axes={}}function n(t){this.internal=new l(this),this.internal

See the error message here:

[image]

Stack trace:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you show the rest of the stack trace? Should appear when you click on the grey arrow to the left

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/mx7Qjy1.png

Comment: Ruben Thanks, i edited it above and added the stack trace

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Uncaught Error: Mismatched anonymous define() module: function definition(name, global)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23796019/uncaught-error-mismatched-anonymous-define-module-function-definitionname)