# Typescript. How to export two classes (in separate files) in one module?

Tags: typescript

I have two classes declared in two separate files.

**a.ts**

```
export class AClass {

  public constructor () {
    console.log('AClass');
  }

}
```

**b.ts**

```
export class BClass {

  public constructor () {
    console.log('BClass');
  }

}
```

I want to merge them in one module. How I can realise it?

```
///<reference path='a.ts' />
///<reference path='b.ts' />

module Common {

  export class A extends AClass {}
  export class B extends BClass {}

}
```

says:

> Cannot find name 'AClass'.

and

> Cannot find name 'BClass'.

I can import classes

```
import AClass = require('a');
import BClass = require('b');

module Common {

}
```

But how I can correctly export them?

Cannot find any information in documentation. Please, tell me the best way to realise declarations in one module? Thank you in advance

Comment: Ther is a difference between internal and external modules : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KDrWLMUY0R0&hd=1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you declare class like you showed you include it in the 'global' namespace. To declare class inside a module just wrap it in module declaration:

```
module Common{
    export class ClassA{}
}
```

you can redeclare module in multiple files only one javascript object will be created for the module.

Comment: But if module contains many classes - source file will be no readable. I want to separate classes in several files

Comment: As I've written yes you can. Typescript is smart this way its not a problem. Just wrap each file in module declaration and you'll get what you want.

Comment: Maybe I not understand correctly. So, I can make two source files with same module but separate class? And if I need only one file, I need to compile files into one .js?

Comment: Typescript compiler will generate one js file for each ts file, but there are ways to bundle your js files into single file.

Comment: this answer is not good because it does not address the OP's problem about multiple files and does not provide an example of how to do so

Answer (score 25):

I do it like this:

**m/a.ts**

```
export class A {
}
```

**m/b.ts**

```
export class B {
}
```

**m/index.ts**

```
export { A } from './a.ts';
export { B } from './b.ts';
```

And then I do:
**consumer.ts**

```
import { A, B } from './m';
```

Answer (score 5):

You have `export` in front of your class declarations:

```
export class AClass {
```

This turns that source file into an external module. This means that you will need to use `import`/`require` from another module:

```
import a = require("a");

module Common {
    export class A extends a.AClass {}
}
```

Note that `AClass` appears to be a member of `a` because that's what I imported its containing module as.

Alternatively you could rename `a` module after a single class that it contains, e.g.

**AClass.ts**

```
class AClass {
  public constructor () {
    console.log('AClass');
  }    
}

export = AClass;
```

By "assigning" to `export` we make that class be the entire single output of module. Hence in another module:

```
import AClass = require("AClass");

var a = new AClass(); // no prefix needed
```

This can be tidier if your module only exports a single class (or function).

Comment: Hm. Maybe it is offtopic, but If I using require, I receive error "Mismatched anonymous define() module: function (require, exports) {
}". Cannot find a reason

Comment: Where do you get that error? In TS compilation? It looks like an AMD wrapper.

Comment: in browser console, compilation was successfull

Comment: Yes, that appears to be due to misuse of AMD/requireJS, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15371918/mismatched-anonymous-define-module

Comment: Yeah, I am read this topic before question. But cannot understood what I should to change (maybe my English is not enough). I have html file only with two script tags (require.js and compiled common.js)

Comment: This generates the error "Cannot compile modules unless the '--module' flag is provided.". Where can I provide this 'flag' ?