# lodash loaded through requirejs and with a script throws "Mismatched anonymous define" error

Tags: npm, requirejs, underscore.js, lodash, amd

I am working on an application that uses requirejs and loads underscore with it but also loads underscore as a node_module using a script. Since we needed functionality found in lodash I decided to replace underscore with lodash in requirejs and in script tags. While it was working with underscore when I replaced it with lodash I started getting:

```
Uncaught Error: Mismatched anonymous define() module: function () {
      return _;
    }
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#mismatch
```

I am using the following npm versions:

`requirejs "2.1.5"`
`underscore: "1.3.3"`
and I want to install 
`lodash: "4.5.1"`

Here is the requirejs config part that I can post:

```
 require.config({
        waitSeconds: 15,
        "paths": {
            underscore: "../../node_modules/lodash/lodash",
            jquery: "lib/jquery-1.7.2",
            Backbone: "lib/backbone",
            moment: "lib/moment-2.0.0",
            text: "lib/text",
            alertify: "lib/alertify",
            datatables: "lib/jquery.dataTables",
            datatablesjqueryui: "lib/dataTables.jqueryui"
        },
        "shim": {
           XYZ: ["underscore","jquery", ...]
           ...
        }
    });
```

- The above is part of a concat file that contains also `node_modules/requirejs/require.js` before it
- I also have another concat after it with the rest of the libraries that include lodash in it.
- Both concat files are added using a `<script>` tag.
- In the last concat I have a lot of files that do

`var _ = require("underscore");`
or have it in their define dependencies like `define(["underscore"],function(_) { ... });`

so hopefully i won't need to change anything there

I would appreciate if someone can explain why this happens only with lodash and not underscore. And if there is a solution that will let me add lodash in the concatenated file after it was imported/required through requirejs.

**Per possible duplicate:** I made sure there are no anonymous defines in the application and I made sure there is no underscore loaded anywhere. So the question is different because I only changed the path from underscore to dash library for the whole application and nothing else.

Thanks!

Comment: It doesn't happen only with lodash. It happens when you use lodash AND underscore. They both use the same variable name `_`. If you're going to use lodash, get rid of underscore. It's a superset anyway.

Comment: Thanks @cdbajorin but in my require js config "underscore" points to the lodash library.. so technically there is no underscore

Comment: Post the code you're using to load lodash

Comment: @cdbajorin I posted the require.config (part of it) that I am using.. lodash is also concatenated to a concat file that is loaded after the require.js configuration. There are a LOT of places that use underscore as a require/define dependency

Comment: @cdbajorin even tried adding in my shim:

      ```"lodash": {
            exports: "_"
        },
        "underscore": {
            exports: "_"
        },``` without any luck

Comment: I'm still not fully understanding what you've posted, as you have some code in your post, and some explanations in the comments. It's hard to put together. I believe your issue is that you need to add it to the `define` section as `["underscore"], function(_) { ... })`, not in the shim.

Comment: @cdbajorin hopefully the setup is more clear now. Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mismatched anonymous define() module](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15371918/mismatched-anonymous-define-module)

Comment: @Louis this doesn't answer my question - the only thing I changed was the path from underscore to lodash in my config. I don't see why this would cause my application to fail. The error is coming directly from lodash library that does ```return _;```

Comment: @MichailMichailidis The set of possible causes for the error you are getting limited to a well defined set, and these causes are addressed in the answers to the other question.

Comment: @Louis I have read the documentation but that doesn't answer the question why keeping everything the same and switching from underscore to lodash I get this error. I want to know why specifically lodash.