# Unable to Add Selected Product(s) to Order

Tags: javascript, php, magento-2.0

I tried to create admin layout file. In that file I included js files as follows

```
    <head>
    <title>
        My title
    </title>
    <css src="Vendor_Mymodule::css/custom.css"/>
    <script src="Magento_Sales::order/giftoptions_tooltip.js"/>
    <script src="Magento_ConfigurableProduct::js/configurable.js"/>
    <script src="Magento_Sales::order/create/scripts.js"/>
    <script src="Magento_Catalog::catalog/product/composite/configure.js"/>
    <script src="Magento_Sales::order/create/giftmessage.js"/>
    <block type="adminhtml/template" name="optional_zip_countries" as="optional_zip_countries" template="Magento_Directory::js/optional_zip_countries.phtml" />
</head>
```

Also in added my blocks inside

```
<referenceContainer name="content"></referenceContainer>
```

I'm getting following errors as in the snapshot.

[JS Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CVosS.png)

When I commented the included script tags first five console errors disappears. When I commented entire blocks inside the reference container last error is disappearing.

My issue is on clicking the button 'Add Selected Product(s) to Order' after selecting the product 'headphone' and adding quantity, another console error

> (index):249 Uncaught ReferenceError: order is not defined(…)

is appearing and none of the products are adding.

My Magento version is 2.1.

Comment: @Forklift Thanks for replying. I'm developing a custom module. Am i have to include jQuery on that? Can u explain how i will include the same. I added a requirejs-config.js already

Comment: Actually, check here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15371918/mismatched-anonymous-define-module