# Error when trying to deploy ethereum contract, probably due to meteor's modules/scripts

Tags: meteor, requirejs, ethereum

I have my meteor project
which when i run i get the following warnings:
First warning:

```
 Mismatched anonymous define() module: function () { return BigNumber; }
      intakeDefines @ aramk_requirejs.js?hash=a2cd915…:1278
      (anonymous) @ aramk_requirejs.js?hash=a2cd915…:1469
```

Second warning:{...}

```
Mismatched anonymous define() module: function () { return utf8; }
```

and when i run my project i get the following error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Right-hand side of 'instanceof' is not callable
at isBigNumber (http://localhost:3000/packages/modules.js?hash=6e90e44e0c2b18ef12cb22415a388acb1e06ad7f:5598:19)
at toBigNumber (http://localhost:3000/packages/modules.js?hash=6e90e44e0c2b18ef12cb22415a388acb1e06ad7f:5465:9)
at Object.fromDecimal (http://localhost:3000/packages/modules.js?hash=6e90e44e0c2b18ef12cb22415a388acb1e06ad7f:5343:18)
at http://localhost:3000/packages/modules.js?hash=6e90e44e0c2b18ef12cb22415a388acb1e06ad7f:2613:30
at Array.forEach (native)
at inputTransactionFormatter (http://localhost:3000/packages/modules.js?hash=6e90e44e0c2b18ef12cb22415a388acb1e06ad7f:2612:8)
at http://localhost:3000/packages/modules.js?hash=6e90e44e0c2b18ef12cb22415a388acb1e06ad7f:2910:28
at Array.map (native)
at Method.formatInput (http://localhost:3000/packages/modules.js?hash=6e90e44e0c2b18ef12cb22415a388acb1e06ad7f:2909:32)
at Method.toPayload (http://localhost:3000/packages/modules.js?hash=6e90e44e0c2b18ef12cb22415a388acb1e06ad7f:2935:23)
```

The line of code where the problem occurs is this: `web3.eth.contract(abi).new({data: code,gas:10000}, function (err, contract) {..irrelevant code..}` After searching on the internet I think that it is require.js's fault and how the scripts are called but still don't know how to fix it. I already looked over the documentation but still need some help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mismatched anonymous define() module](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15371918/mismatched-anonymous-define-module)

Comment: Hi Louis, I already saw this post but still have trouble fixing the problem

Comment: The answers to that post give you the entire set of conditions under which the error you get can happen. So you are surely hitting one of them. We cannot tell you *why* you are hitting one of them because we do not have access to your code. You would need to put a [mcve] in your question to allow us to determine whether there *is* something beyond the other question that needs answering. By the way, "Mismatched anonymous define" is not a *warning*, it is an *error*.