# Phonegap generating socket io scripts?

Tags: javascript, cordova, requirejs, phonegap-desktop-app

I am working on a PhoneGap App and I tried implementing Typescript and requiredjs but for some reason. I am getting this error:

[image]

I dont understand why Phonegap is generating or somehow using socket.io

This is my structure

I have an `appLoader.ts`

```
declare let requirejs:any;
    declare let $:any;
    declare let angular:any;
    requirejs.config({

      shim: {
          "jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min":["jquery-1.11.3.min"],
          "angular.min":["jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min"],
          "index":["angular.min"],
          "ngCart":["angular.min"],
          "app":["angular.min","ngCart"],
          "app_controller":["app"],
          "controller/searchPostCondeController":["app_controller"]
      }
    });

    let dependencies = ["jquery-1.11.3.min","jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min","index","angular.min","ngCart","app","app_controller","controller/searchPostCondeController"];

    requirejs(dependencies, function() {
        angular.bootstrap($('html'), ['myApp']);

    });
```

I don't have any socket io that I am using. I also notice this

[image]

There's a sock io inclusion after my requirejs which I am not including manually. Or embedded in my HTML.

Comment: have you edited require.js ?

Comment: @AkshayTilekar that is my current requirejs, what should I edit on it?

Comment: im asking did you edited it ?

Comment: @AkshayTilekar Ah I see. Nope. I didn't touch the require.js

Comment: ok,which editor you are using?

Comment: have a look at this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15371918/mismatched-anonymous-define-module